# How to show reply and retweet icons using hover effect with css?

Tags: css, hover

I want to show the reply and retweet icons while hovering over my tweet using css. I am enable to change the background color using code:

```
ul.statuses li:hover {
        background-color:#F7F7F7;
        display: inherit;
    }
```

But unable to show icons using hover effect on same tweet text. How to show both change background color and icons for single tweet?

Comment: Is there a site where you've seen this effect in use?  I think an example of what you want will help answer this question.

Comment: Like in twitter when we we take mouse over a tweet the background color of that particular tweet changes and it shows the reply, retweet and favorite icon links for that tweet on the top right corner. I want the effects something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to show the icons with hover effect using code:

```
    ul.statuses .buttons{
            display: none;
    }
    ul.statuses li:hover .buttons {
            display: inline-block;
    }
```

And the html code for showing the hover effect for dummy tweets is:

```
<ul id="status" class="statuses">
              <li>Sample tweets. Sample tweets. Sample tweets. Sample tweets. Sample tweets.
              <p id="iconlinks" class="buttons">
                <a href="#" id="reply"><i class="icon-share-alt" title="Reply"></i></a>
            <a href="#" id="retweet"><i class="icon-retweet" title="Retweet"></i></a>
            <a href="#" id="favorite"><i class="icon-star" title="Favorite"></i></a>
            <a href="#" id="mail"><i class="icon-envelope" title="Mail"></i></a>
            <a href="#" id="assign"><i class="icon-user" title="assign"></i></a>
               </p>
                  </li>
                  <li>Sample tweets. Sample tweets. Sample tweets. 
                    <p id="iconlinks" class="buttons">
                      <a href="#" id="reply"><i class="icon-share-alt" title="Reply"></i></a>
                      <a href="#" id="retweet"><i class="icon-retweet" title="Retweet"></i></a>
          <a href="#" id="favorite"><i class="icon-star" title="Favorite"></i></a>
                      <a href="#" id="mail"><i class="icon-envelope" title="Mail"></i></a>
                      <a href="#" id="assign"><i class="icon-user" title="assign"></i></a>
                  </p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
```

I have created icons using twitter bootstrap and placed the in "buttons" class.

Thanks for your quick response guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.statuses li:hover {
  background-color:#F7F7F7;
  display: inherit;
  content: url(/img.gif)
}
```

you can use css to show an image with the content attribute

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/content

Comment: Content Property is not supported by IE6 or IE7. Although they are being phased out.

Comment: yes, this is true..and someday soon, no one will ever have to type IE6 again..muhahahah  however, OP didn't designate that as an issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the display property, which may change the spacing of your front end, as the DOM changes, try:

```
ul.statuses li {opacity:0}

ul.statuses li:hover {opacity:1}
```

This way, the effect from the user's perspective is the same, but your DOM won't be bouncing around. Try adding a CSS transition to make it even smoother.